# electron-forge, packaged application shows blank screen

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-forge

I'm developing a electron app and using electron-forge, I started a new project with the webpack & typescript template, did not do any major changes to the configuration, however the time came to package the application all I get is a blank screen.

If I start my app with `yarn start` everything works, but after running `yarn package` and opening the app all I get is a blank screen, the console shows no error at all, it remains blank.

the main index.ts file:

```js
import { app, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import path from "path";
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY: any;
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY: any;

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require("electron-squirrel-startup")) {
  // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY
    }
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};
```

the renderer code:

```js
import "../assets/base.css";
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));

declare let module: { hot: any };

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./App", () => {
    const NewApp = require("./App").default;

    render(<NewApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
  });
}
```

The only change I did to the webpack configuration was adding postCSS to load tailwind other than that it is the default configuration, the app compiles and the .app file is generated however nothing is loaded.

The terminal output also does not show any error:

```
> yarn package
yarn run v1.19.2
warning ../package.json: No license field
$ electron-forge package
✔ Checking your system
✔ Compiling Main Process Code
⠋ Compiling Renderer TemplateStarting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
✔ Compiling Renderer Template
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
✔ Preparing native dependencies
✔ Packaging Application
✨  Done in 8.06s.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Let me check the file structure after you build the app

Comment: blank means, possibly this ```MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY``` is not correct at prod mode

Comment: If you can attach the webpackPluginConfig then it will be much better

Answer (score 0):

After going through hell and back on this issue, I guess I was able to figure out  a possible solution. Although this is a very old thread. But I just decided to give a response incase someone comes across this problem like I did, but didn't get any pointers. Ironically, I recently came across a post on Quora about the most frustrating aspects of programming, Which included when a programmer searches or posts a question on ***StackOverflow*** without getting an answer or comment!

In my own case, I am using the Svelte frontend framework with electron-forge and Webpack. Which should be similar with your configuration, except for the part were you're using React.

1. Firstly, I had to update the way the application is loaded into the main application window. Such that when the application is in development, it uses the default Webpack main window application entry constant. Otherwise it loads the application from file system. Shown as follows:

   ```
   mainWindow.loadURL((app.isPackaged)? `file://${__dirname}/../renderer/main_window/index.html`:MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);
   ```
2. Also ensure that Webpack JS bundle file (`index.js` or `build.js`) script tag in the `index.html` file is loaded from the correct directory. In my own case, the `index.js` file  was in the same directory with the `index.html` file, but Webpack was loading it from a different directory. Since it is being loaded automatically by the electron-webpack-plugin in development.
3. At this point the application should work. However, another issue that you may encounter is routing. If you're using `react-router`, which I guess is quite similar to svelte-navigator.  In this case, you may have to use memory or hash based routing, since electron is a minimal browser and does not support browser type navigation.  To achieve navigation in svelte, I created a memory history, loaded it to the `Router` and used the `navigate` function in the newly created history for navigation around the application. Shown as follows:

   ```
   import {Router, Route, createHistory, createMemorySource } from "svelte-navigator"

   const history = createHistory(createMemorySource());

   const {navigate} = history;
   window.navigate = navigate;

   <Router {history}>
      /* -------- */
   </Router>
   ```

Hence, whenever I need to navigate to a route I can navigate as such:

```
<a href="#" on:click={ () => window.navigate("routepath") }>Home</a>
```

OR

```
function submit() {
       window.navigate("routepath");
}
```